# Make a Session never timeout OR redirect user to home page. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am working on a asp.net 3.5 web application  the session time-out is set to 24 hours but a recycling of ASPNet process on the server is scheduled to trigger everyday at 3:00 A.M. is causing the session to timed out.

What is the best solution and how to achieve it :

My code should constantly listen to the server and  show a message to user and redirect him to home page after session is expired?

OR

A solution which makes a session to never timeout.

Thanks in advance BB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this
 http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article86.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Make your session be [stored in SQL server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604) instead of in-memory.  That way when the server recycles it wont affect the sessions at all.