# How to increase the time of logged in user in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

I want the user to be logged in until the user closes the browser window or specifically logs out. how this can be done? Should I use UserIsOnlineTimeWindow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946790/make-a-session-never-timeout-or-redirect-user-to-home-page-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Use a javascript "keep alive" mechanism.

You will have to use a javascript setInterval to keep making ajax requests to your server.

This keeps the session alive for as long as the browser is open.

Note that is is a security risk, it is usually good to stop making these requests by clearing the interval after a definitely amount of time.

Extending the session timeout by setting it to very large number won't scale very well for a large number of users

Answer (score 0):

You can set the session timeout in web.config...the max valid value of which 525601 minutes (1 year) - default is 20mins

```
<system.web> 
<sessionState timeout="20" /> 
<system.web>
```

Comment: The max value is one day, 1440 minutes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: not accoring to MSDN it's not http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Beware: Extending the session timeout will mean that those sessions will take up memory for the entire period - can your server handle that?